# Magento (CE 1.3) - Filter productCollection where stock quantity is 0

Tags: magento, filter, magento-1.3

**Magento 1.3**

I'm trying to filter out of stock items from the productCollection. Using:

```
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('neq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED))
```

I can filter by status, but in this store , enabled products can still have 0 quantity.

Using:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 0))
```

returns a 'qty' is not an attribute error.

```
$this->_productCollection = $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->setStoreId($storeId)
                            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('neq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED))                              
                            ->setPageSize($this->getToolbarBlock()->getLimit());
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you have to join stock items collection to achieve this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
)
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('eq' => 0));
```

In case you need no `catalog/product` data at all (except the product id), but only want to know which product ids have a quantity of zero in general, you also could use:

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
->getCollection()
->addQtyFilter('=', 0);
```

Comment: this is not working always but depends if it is selected or not `Manage stock`

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna throw this in a simple module look below:

app/code/local/Company/InStockOnly/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

<global>
  <models>
    <company_instockonly>
      <class>Company_InStockOnly_Model</class>
    </company_instockonly>
  </models>
</global>

<frontend>
  <events>
    <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
      <observers>
        <company_instockonly_list>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>company_instockonly/observer</class>
          <method>addInStockOnlyFilter</method>
        </company_instockonly_list>
      </observers>
    </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
  </events>
</frontend>

</config>
```

app/code/local/Company/InStockOnly/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Company_InStockOnly_Model_Observer {

  /**
   * Observes the catalog_block_product_list_collection event
   */
  public function addInStockOnlyFilter($observer){
    $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()
      ->joinField('stock_status','cataloginventory/stock_status','stock_status',
        'product_id=entity_id', array(
          'stock_status' => Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK,
          'website_id' => Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId(),
        ))
    ;
  }
}
```

Then make Magento discover your module:

app/etc/modules/Company_InStockOnly.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_InStockOnly>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Company_InStockOnly>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use if($_product->isSaleable()): on your products list output